# Session not works in C#

Tags: c#, session

i try to make an session in C#. I just started learning a while ago and I am stuck here. The code I am tried:

First:

```
Session["Status"] = "hehehe";
```

Result:

```
The name 'Session' does not exist in the current context
```

Second test:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["Status"] = "hehehe";
```

Result:

```
The name 'HttpContext' does not exist in the current context
```

So i am currently stuck here, In top I am using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

Comment: you need to add `using System.Web;`

Comment: -1 for lack of effort

Comment: What's the point of `Session` in Windows Forms app (assuming after `System.Windows.Forms` using)?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Caleb that was right. I cannot accept your answer when it is in comments tho :/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use it in Windows Forms (as `using System.Windows.Forms;` tells). Windows applications do not have the concept of sessions as sessions are meant to be used on the servers to manage the clients that are connected to the server. If you're developing an app that connects to a server (e.g. via API), you may need to manage the session cookie that is sent to your app from the server.